# Is query.next() slow?

Tags: python, performance, loops, iterator, pyqt

I'm using PyQt for a GUI software. I also use a sqlite database to feed the software with data.

Somewhere in my code, I have this method:

```
def loadNotifications(self):

    """Method to find the number of unread articles,
    for each search. Load a list of id, for the unread articles,
    in each table. And a list of id, for the concerned articles, for
    each table"""

    count_query = QtSql.QSqlQuery(self.bdd)
    count_query.setForwardOnly(True)

    # Don't treat the articles if it's the main tab, it's
    # useless because the article will be concerned for sure
    for table in self.list_tables_in_tabs[1:]:

        # Empty these lists, because when loadNotifications is called
        # several times during the use, the nbr of unread articles is
        # added to the nbr of notifications
        table.list_new_ids = []
        table.list_id_articles = []

        # Try to speed things up
        append_new = table.list_new_ids.append
        append_articles = table.list_id_articles.append

        req_str = self.refineBaseQuery(table.base_query, table.topic_entries, table.author_entries)
        print(req_str)
        count_query.exec_(req_str)

        start_time = datetime.datetime.now()
        i = 0

        while count_query.next():
            i += 1
            record = count_query.record()

            append_articles(record.value('id'))

            if record.value('new') == 1:
                append_new(record.value('id'))

        print(datetime.datetime.now() - start_time)
        print("Nbr of entries processed: {}".format(i))
```

Let's assume this loop has ~400 entries to process. It takes about one second, and I think it's too long. I tried to optimize the process as much as I could, but it still takes too much time.

Here is what the previous method typically prints:

```
SELECT * FROM papers WHERE id IN(320, 1320, 5648, 17589, 20092, 20990, 49439, 58378, 65251, 68772, 73509, 86859, 90594)
0:00:00.001403
Nbr of entries processed: 13
SELECT * FROM papers WHERE topic_simple LIKE '% 3D print%'
0:00:00.591745
Nbr of entries processed: 81
SELECT * FROM papers WHERE id IN (5648, 11903, 14258, 30587, 40339, 55691, 57383, 58378, 62951, 65251, 68772, 87295)
0:00:00.000478
Nbr of entries processed: 12
SELECT * FROM papers WHERE topic_simple LIKE '% Python %'
0:00:00.596490
Nbr of entries processed: 9
SELECT * FROM papers WHERE topic_simple LIKE '% Raspberry pi %' OR topic_simple LIKE '% arduino %'
0:00:00.988276
Nbr of entries processed: 5
SELECT * FROM papers WHERE topic_simple LIKE '% sensor array%' OR topic_simple LIKE '% biosensor %'
0:00:00.996164
Nbr of entries processed: 433
SELECT * FROM papers WHERE id IN (320, 540, 1320, 1434, 1860, 4527, 5989, 6022, 6725, 6978, 7268, 8625, 9410, 9814, 9850, 10608, 13219, 15572, 15794, 19345, 19674, 19899, 20990, 22530, 26443, 26535, 28721, 29089, 30923, 31145, 31458, 31598, 32069, 34129, 35820, 36142, 36435, 37546, 39188, 39952, 40949, 41764, 43529, 43610, 44184, 45206, 49210, 49807, 50279, 50943, 51536, 51549, 52921, 52967, 54610, 56036, 58087, 60490, 62133, 63051, 63480, 63535, 64861, 66906, 68107, 68328, 69021, 71797, 73058, 74974, 75331, 77697, 78138, 80152, 80539, 82172, 82370, 82840, 86859, 87467, 91528, 92167)
0:00:00.002891
Nbr of entries processed: 82
SELECT * FROM papers WHERE id IN (7043, 41643, 44688, 50447, 64723, 72601, 81006, 82380, 84285)
0:00:00.000348
Nbr of entries processed: 9
```

Is this the better way ? Can I get better results ?

NOTE: the time displayed is the time needed to run the loop, not the time needed to run the query.

I tried `count_query.setForwardOnly(True)`, as mentioned in the doc, but it had no effect on the perfs.

EDIT:
Here is test database with ~600 entries:
[database](http://sd-1.archive-host.com/membres/up/71854706618929057/test.sql)

Answer (score 1):

Obviously I can't test this, so I don't know if it will make a significant difference, but you could try using index-based look-ups:

```
id_index = count_query.record().indexOf('id')
new_index = count_query.record().indexOf('new')
while count_query.next():
    record = count_query.record()
    id_value = record.value(id_index)
    append_articles(id_value)
    if record.value(new_index) == 1:
        append_new(id_value)
```

**UPDATE**:

Using your sample db, I cannot reproduce the issue you are seeing, and I also found my method above is about twice as fast as your original one. Here's some sample output:

```
IDs: 660, Articles: 666
IDs: 660, Articles: 666
IDs: 660, Articles: 666
test(index=False): 0.19050272400090762
IDs: 660, Articles: 666
IDs: 660, Articles: 666
IDs: 660, Articles: 666
test(index=True): 0.09384496400161879
```

Test case:

```
import sys, os, timeit
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
from PyQt4.QtSql import QSqlDatabase, QSqlQuery

def test(index=False):
    count_query = QSqlQuery('select * from results')
    list_new_ids = []
    list_id_articles = []
    append_new = list_new_ids.append
    append_articles = list_id_articles.append
    if index:
        id_index = count_query.record().indexOf('id')
        new_index = count_query.record().indexOf('new')
        while count_query.next():
            record = count_query.record()
            id_value = record.value(id_index)
            append_articles(id_value)
            if record.value(new_index) == 1:
                append_new(id_value)
    else:
        while count_query.next():
            record = count_query.record()
            append_articles(record.value('id'))
            if record.value('new') == 1:
                append_new(record.value('id'))
    print('IDs: %d, Articles: %d' % (
        len(list_new_ids), len(list_id_articles)))

class Window(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Window, self).__init__()
        self.button = QtGui.QPushButton('Test', self)
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.handleButton)
        layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(self.button)
        self.database = QSqlDatabase.addDatabase("QSQLITE")
        path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'tmp/perf-test.db')
        self.database.setDatabaseName(path)
        self.database.open()

    def handleButton(self):
        for stmt in 'test(index=False)', 'test(index=True)':
            print('%s: %s' % (stmt, timeit.timeit(
                stmt, 'from __main__ import test', number=3)))

if __name__ == '__main__':

    import sys
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    window.setGeometry(600, 300, 200, 100)
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Nope sorry, nothing changed. The perfs were the same, the loop takes almost exactly the same time (it might be slightly less good, but I don't think it's statistically significant).

Comment: @Rififi. Thought you might say that. It's hard to make useful suggestions without a realistic sample db to test.

Comment: Yep I know, I prepared a test database, see my edit.

Comment: @Rififi. See my updated answer. If you don't get similar results using my test case, you obviously need to provide more information about your real code and system setup.

Comment: Thank you very much for your hard work. I got very similar results with your test case, so I edited my question and provided the full code of my method, along with some output. Looking at the results, it seems that the problem comes from the 'like' queries. Don't you agree ? Note: the time displayed is not the time used to perform the query, it is the time to run the loop.

Comment: @Rififi. Sorry, but I don't see any "full code" in your question - so it looks like my "hard work" was wasted. When using my test case, I don't see any significant difference when using `LIKE` queries.

Comment: You can't see the full code ? Now it's the complete function, called loadNotifications. It is where the code of the loop was. And just a bit under that, there are some typical LIKE queries that take much more time than normal ones.

Comment: @Rififi. It's clearly not a complete function: I cannot run it without a whole load of other code that you haven't shown. Do you expect me to rewrite it all after I already provided you with a working test case? And as I said in my previous comment: I tested your `LIKE` queries, and it made no difference.

Comment: I'm really sorry, I'm doing my best to find out where the issue comes from. Actually, it doesn't really come from my code. Here are the steps to reproduce my problem with your test case: increase the size of the database I gave you: ```Insert Into results Select * from results```, until about 10k entries. Then use this query: ```SELECT * FROM results WHERE topic_simple LIKE '% countercurrent %'```. You will see the loop takes most of the time of the function.

Comment: What I mean: with a 10k entries database, if the query returned 200 articles, the loop will take 100 ms. With a 600 entries database, if the query returned 200 articles, the loop will take ~0 ms.

Comment: @Rififi. Thanks for coming up with a better test. However, unless I've misunderstood you, I still cannot reproduce your problem. Using your query on a db with 10656 rows, my test case returns 208 records in about half a second. For comparison, `SELECT * FROM results` takes about 1.5 seconds. This doesn't seem out of line with my original set of test results, given that the db is 16 times bigger. I also loaded the 10k db into [sqlitebrowser](http://sqlitebrowser.org/) and ran the same query. It returned 208 rows in 417ms - so only about a  tenth of second faster than pyqt.

Comment: @Rififi. It might be useful to state what platform you are testing on, and what specific versions of Qt and PyQt you are using. I'm testing on linux, with python 3.5.0, qt 4.8.7, and pyqt 4.11.4.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95019/discussion-between-rififi-and-ekhumoro).